# How to access a Virtual Host created by XAMPP from Virtual Machine?

Tags: web-applications, xampp, virtual-machine, virtualhost

I'm using XAMPP to setup my web development environment on Mac. Also for test different browsers I installed Virtual Machine(One WIN7 and one WIN8) on my Mac.

I keep the default XAMPP page to localhost as default. And created an virtual host named arthur.local which pointed to my Sites folder to do all my projects.

Now I could use browsers on mac to access my project, just by typing arthur.local in the URL and am good to go.

However I can't access this Virtual Host from the Virtual Machine I created. I could access localhost by using the IP address, but I don't know how could I access my virtual host? What I should give the the browser?

Here are the setup for my virtual host in XAMPP:

```
#Arthur's Host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Arthur.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Arthur0902/Sites"
    <Directory "/Users/Arthur0902/Sites">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

All clients that wish to browse to this virtual host need to be able to resolve "arthur.local".

Two answers: "DNS", and/or "/etc/hosts".

On Windows, the "/etc/hosts" file is actually "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4. I think I have something in my hosts file:

127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.0.1 Arthur.local

But I have no idea what or how should I change it....Could you give me some hits?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with your virtual machines to get a common URL.  But for this purpose, check Adobe Browser Lab, it will hlp you more.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can add the following line to the "hosts" files on your client machines (VMs running Windows 7/8)

```
10.1.1.4         arthur.local
```

---

Where "10.1.1.4" is the actual IP address of your host machine (the Mac running XAMPP). If you don't know this, run "ifconfig" from a command line.

---

The 127.0.0.1 address is just shorthand for the loopback device/local host.

It works on the Mac because it points to itself (the Mac) where the server is. 
It *doesn't* work in the VM because it points to itself (the VM) where the server ain't.